# what to do when the source code uses a version of go that is disabled

Tags: go, installation, homebrew, version, goland

The source code's go.mod file uses go 1.16 but I can't install this go version since it has been disabled and I get the following: Error: go@1.16 has been disabled because it is not supported upstream!

I'm not authorised to change the source code but I can't run it without having go 1.16 installed. What can I do here?

tried

```
brew install go@1.16
```

Comment: Even if go1.16 is required, you should at least attempt to use the latest patch release. If you can’t use go1.16 because it’s no longer supported, and you can’t change the source, then you are out of luck. At least one of those things must change.

Answer (score 0):

The [go version directive](https://go.dev/doc/modules/gomod-ref#go) in the go.mod file is just a *minimum* Go version for that library, not the one you have to use.  As Go is backward compatible any Go version *after* 1.16 will work but ones before it will not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, this is what I'm seeing when I try to run the application with my current version of Golang: You have incorrect version of Golang (1.22). Version 1.16 must be used.

Comment: That suggests the application itself is fixing the version, what application is it and can you look in the source to see where this error is coming from?